# Salesforce Batch Governor Limit

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, soql

I am running the following batch and I am making a query inside of a for loop, here is the query:

```
lgm=[select Group.Name, group.type,group.id, group.ownerID from GroupMember where UserOrGroupId =: u.id];
```

The batch is looping into every user in the org, and gets its permission sets, and the public group and queues to which he is assigned and also the name and id of that user, then populate those informations into a custom object called ConsolidatedUser

I have not yet run the batch with a large amount of records to see if the governor limits are reached and would like your opinion, as per now the batch works correctly,
can I ask you how many soql queries are allowed per transaction in a batch to make sure that I don't get into any conflict. 
here is my code and thank you for your help.

```
global class TDTRMIS_GetUserDetails implements  Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

global string UserPermissionSets='';
global string UserGroups='';
global string UserQueues='';
global integer i;

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, name, (select PermissionSet.Name, AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignments)  from user' 
        );
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<User> scope){
        // process each batch of records

                // process each batch of records

        List<ConsolidatedUser__c> lcu = new List<ConsolidatedUser__c>();
        list<GroupMember> lgm= new list<GroupMember>();
        for (User u : scope)
        {


            ConsolidatedUser__c cu= new ConsolidatedUser__c();
            lgm=[select Group.Name, group.type,group.id, group.ownerID from GroupMember where UserOrGroupId =: u.id];


            for(PermissionSetAssignment ps : u.PermissionSetAssignments)
                {
                UserPermissionSets=UserPermissionSets+ps.PermissionSet.name+'|';        
                }


            for(GroupMember gm : lgm)
            {

                 if(gm.group.type=='Regular' )
                 {
                 UserGroups=UserGroups+gm.group.Name+'|';
                 }

                 else if(gm.group.type=='Queue' )
                 {
                 UserQueues=UserQueues+gm.group.Name+'|';  
                 } 

            }  


            cu.PermSet__c=UserPermissionSets ;  
            cu.PublicGroupList__c=UserGroups;
            cu.QueueGroupList__c= UserQueues;
            cu.User_Lookup__c=u.id;    
            cu.name=u.name;
            lcu.add(cu);
        } 

    try{
    upsert lcu;
    }

    catch(exception e)
    {
    system.debug(e);
    }

    }  

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

    //to be added later

    }    

}
```

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Batch Apex is considered asynchronous Apex, so the "Total number of SOQL queries issued" limit in your case will be 200.
This limit is for one execution of the batch.

I suggest you remove the SOQL from your user for loop. List collect the user ID's in a list within the user for loop and then make a single SOQL query to get the GroupMember list using the user ID list.

Here is a related link : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176644&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 0):

This explains all you need to know about SOQL governor limits:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Basically, the SOQL governor limit per transaction is 100.

It's never a good idea to put SOQL queries within loops. See the following for alternatives:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Comment: Thank you for your response, I see two types of limits for SOQL queries; 100 and 200 queries, can I ask you which one is going to be the limit for this batch. Thank you

Comment: As @arun-kumar mentioned in his answer, 200 is the limit for batch transactions.